# Curried Functions in Standard ML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, currying

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to learn about curried functions.  Here's what I understand so far; suppose I have a function:

```
fun curry (a b c) = a * b * c;
```

or

```
fun curry a b c = a * b * c;
```

In ML, I can only have one argument so the first function uses a 3-tuple to get around this / get access to `a`, `b`, and `c`.

In the second example, what I really have is:

```
fun ((curry a) b) c
```

where `curry a` returns a function, and 
`(curry a) b` returns a function and `((curry a) b) c` returns another function.  A few questions:

1) Why is this preferable to using a tuple?  Is it just that I can make use of the intermediate functions `curry a` and `(curry a) b`.  My book mentions partial instantiation but not totally clear on it.

2) How do you determine what function `curry a`, `(curry a) b` actually do?  `((curry a) b)` c is just `a * b * c`, right?

Thanks for any help clearing this up,

bclayman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an element of taste in using curried vs. non-curried functions. I don't use curried functions as a matter of course. For example, if were to write a gcd function I would tend to write it as a function designed to operated on a tuple simply because I seldom have use for a defined partially-instantiated gcd function.

Where curried functions are really useful is in defining higher-order functions. Consider `map`. It is easy enough to write a non-curried version:

```
fun mymap (f,[])= []
|   mymap (f,x::xs) = f(x)::mymap(f,xs)
```

It has type `fn : ('a -> 'b) * 'a list -> 'b list` taking a tuple consisting of a function between two types and a list of elements of the input type, returning a list of element of the output type. There is nothing exactly *wrong* with this function, but -- it isn't the same as SML's `map`. The built-in map has type

`fn : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list`

which is curried. What does the curried function do for us? For one thing, it can be thought of as a *function transformer*. You feed map a function, `f`, designed to operate on elements of a given type and it returns as function `map f` which is designed to operate on whole lists of elements. For example, if

```
fun square(x) = x*x;
```

Is a function designed to square `ints` then `val list_square = map square` defines `list_square` as a function which takes a list of elements and returns the list of their squares.

When you use `map` in a call like `map square [1,2,3]` you have to remember that function application is left associative so that this parses as

'(map square) [1,2,3]`. The function`map square`*is* the same as the function`list_square`I defined above. The invocation`map square [1,2,3]`takes that function and applies it to`[1,2,3]`yielding`[1,4,9]`.

The curried version is really nice if you want to define a function, `metamap`, which can be used to apply functions to each element of a matrix thought of as a list of lists. Using the curried version it is as simple as:

```
fun metamap f = map (map f)
```

used like (in the REPL):

```
- metamap square [[1,2],[3,4]];
val it = [[1,4],[9,16]] : int list list
```

The logic is that `map` *lifts* a function from applying to elements to applying to lists. If you want a function to apply to lists of lists (e.g. matrices) just apply `map` twice -- which is all `metamap` does. You *could*, of course, write a version a non-curried version of `metamap` using our noncurried `mymap` function (it wouldn't even be all that hard), but you wouldn't be able to approach the elegance of the 1-line definition above.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about the example I gave.  How would you know what function `curry a` is?  Or `(curry a) b`?  Your answer on why I might want to curry is helpful, thanks!

Comment: `def curry a b = a + b` is equivalent to `def curry a = fn x => a + x` When you define a function you are saying what the function is.  Interpret a definition like `def curry a b = ...` as primarily a definition of what the function `curry a` is.

Comment: @bclayman I edited the post to expand a little more on this point.